# How do I get foreign characters in a select/dropdown list to display properly in IE 7?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, character-encoding

I have tested in IE6, Firefox 3.0.5 and Chrome and they all work. In IE7 it displays as boxes.

For example:

```
<select name="selectact" id="selectact">
<option value="page" selected="selected">网 页</option> 
<option value="news">新 闻</option> 
<option value="trade">行 业</option> 
<option value="area">区 域</option> 
<option value="web">网 站</option> 
<option value="image">图 片</option> 
<option value="mp3">MP3</option> 
<option value="flash">Flash</option> 
<option value="bbs">论坛</option> 
</select>
```

**Note: Characters display ok on the page, just no in drop down**

Comment: I have tried validating and it detects the character encoding ok. I have also tried changing the character encoding to something other that UTF-8 and that didn't work, this is not an ideal option as the drop down should be able to display characters from a variety of languages not just chinese. A bit wierd this problem is only apparent in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [validating](http://validator.w3.org/) the page?  Among other things, that will verify you're specifying a character encoding and only byte sequences that are valid in that encoding.

Comment: I have tried validating and it detects the character encoding ok.

Comment: If that's true, then it could be just a problem with IE's fonts.  I would be extra-careful to ensure the page itself was correct, though.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<select name="selectact" id="selectact" style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
    <option value="page" selected="selected">网 页</option>
    <option value="news">新 闻</option>
    <option value="trade">行 业</option>
    <option value="area">区 域</option>
    <option value="web">网 站</option>
    <option value="image">图 片</option>
    <option value="mp3">MP3</option>
    <option value="flash">Flash</option>
    <option value="bbs">论坛</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the correct [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#spec-char-encoding). Assuming that is Chinese text, you would insert the following meta tag into the head of your document:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-2022-cn">
```

A full list of character sets can be found [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).

Comment: I tried changing the character encoding to something other that UTF-8 and that didn't work, this is not an ideal option as the drop down should be able to display characters from a variety of languages not just chinese.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IE7 version v7.0.5730.13 and higher versions of IE7. IE6 and 8 are okay. Even IE7 version 7.0.5730.11 is reportedly okay. The browser does not choose a Unicode font for some Japanese character ranges. The only workaround that I have found is it force the drop-down to a font that supports Unicode:

font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial